# Why did the bottom freezer in my Whirlpool refrigerator stop working?

Tags: refrigerator

I accidentally left my bottom freezer open overnight and it stopped working. It will no longer freeze and the refrigerator isn’t very cold. I unplugged it for 24 hrs., but it didn’t make a difference. Was told it could be the damper. How do I check to see if the damper has failed?

Comment: Suggest checking with Whirlpool technical staff on its website.

Comment: When you say, "...was told it could be the damper", who told you that?  Was it a service technician?